# Trying to automate allowing push notifications in UI test and UI interruption monitor does not trigger

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing, fastlane-snapshot

I am trying to write a UI test for my iOS Swift app in order to automate screenshots with Fastlane. My app requests push notification permissions in its AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, so when the application is first launched on a new device (which is going to be the case since I will erase the simulator between each running of my UI test), I want the permissions to be allowed before I can interact with the rest of the app. So I followed [this article](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/handling-system-alerts-in-ui-tests/) and here is my UI test's code:

```
import XCTest

class Fastlane_Snapshots: XCTestCase {
    let app = XCUIApplication()

    override func setUp() {
        continueAfterFailure = false
        setupSnapshot(app)
        app.launch()
        addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "System Dialog") {
            (alert) -> Bool in
            print("Interruption running")
            let button = alert.buttons.element(boundBy: 1)
            if button.exists {
                button.tap()
            }
            return true
        }
        app.tap()
    }

    override func tearDown() {

    }

    func testSnapshots() {

    }
}
```

But the UI monitor code is never triggered. When I start recording for the `testSnapshot` method, I see the alert appear in the simulator but it's not dismissed, and when I set a breakpoint on the first line of the UI interruption monitor callback, it doesn't get there.

Any idea what I might have forgotten?

Comment: Do you have any other interruption monitors registered?

Comment: No, that's the only one.

Comment: ever solved this @Sebastien?